# Adding .png image to DrawerLayout gives error

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable, drawerlayout

I am trying to add a image to the top of a side menu (DrawerLayout) in .png format, i imported the image to "drawable" folder and now im calling the image to be shown by:

```
android:src="@drawable/icone"
```

icone is the name of the image, but i get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.bugdroid.menuexe, PID: 5076
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bugdroid.menuexe/com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

I want to put the image here, on the white square:

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVaX9.png)

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/icone"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Sintomas"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Duarte Andrade "
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not .png. Your image does not fit within the available memory. This means memory allocation crosses the heap limit or your process demand a amount of memory that crosses the heap limit.
Given that you are working with limited memory, ideally you only want to load a lower resolution version in memory. The lower resolution version should match the size of the UI component that displays it. An image with a higher resolution does not provide any visible benefit, but still takes up precious memory and incurs additional performance overhead due to additional on the fly scaling.

**Solution**
Try using Glide Library. To use glide library you need to add this to your grandle dependencies:
`compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'` and `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'`

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Finally load your image:

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.icone).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(imageView);
```

[To use Glide, read this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

If Glide doesn't work then try [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
Hope it helps.